# sharedpreferences to keep users login in flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation

I try to to use sharepreferences in my code to keep users login when the `key` is still active in sharedpreferences.. but my apps always redirect users to Login Screen, instead of Home screen after they click back button to exit the app. am I doing mistake in my code?, this is my code

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my splash screen

```
class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  Future check() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final _key= prefs.getString('key');
    if (_key==null) {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new LoginScreen()));
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new BottomTab()));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    new Timer(new Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      check();
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
```

and in my Login screen I have added this code to save my key and then navigate it to Home Screen (BottomTab)

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('key', myKey);

Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext ctx) => BottomTab()));
```

and this is my Home Screen that contains Bottom Tab

```
class _BottomTab extends State<BottomTab> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  _onTap(int index) {
    setState(() => _myindex = index);
  }

  final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomeScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(), 
  ];

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  Widget _myNavigation(int selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _onTap,
        currentIndex: myindex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <MyTab>[
          MyTab(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          MyTab(icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile')),
        ],
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: _myNavigation(_myindex),
      body: PageStorage(
        child: pages[_myindex],
        bucket: bucket,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, can you try adding `await` to your setString method?
await prefs.setString('key', myKey); or maybe check the value of "myKey" because maybe it really is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always land in your Login screen, that's because `_key is null` in the Splash screnn.

So I would look at this line in your Login screen.

```
prefs.setString('key', myKey);
```

Maybe `myKey` is null ??

---

Use the `print()` function to discover your problem and look at the debug console to read the output.

```
// in your splash screen
print(_key);

// in your login screen
print(myKey);
```

Comment: yes, I get null before, so after I rebuilt my app and set my key again.. it works well.. thanks for your help :D